# CakePHP: get associated objects of logged in user

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I try to receive the data of associated models to the current logged in user.
This is my current User model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Website' => array(
            'className'  => 'Website',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

And this is the Website model which is associated to the User model:

```
class Website extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Website';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'classname' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

When I try to get the websites of the logged in user I don't want to set the user_id of the website in a static way in the conditions of the DB request. So I tried to use the associations:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Website->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    // OR
    $this->Website->User->set($this->Auth->user());
}

public function index() {
    $this->set('websites', $this->Website->find('all'));
}
```

But it returns all websites instead of only the ones with the correct user_id.

Is there a way to do it the way i suggest? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Model->find('all') will be retrieving all the records of that model.

Using your belongTo relationship, when you retrieve the User (using find->), Cake will retrieve the websites in the same collection. Depending on how you're handling your authentication, that data might be since the beginning of user session

Comment: This seems like a good solution, the only problem is that Cake now has to do 2 queries in stead of 1 :(

Comment: When you use the belongsTo relationship, Cake makes only one query joining the related tables automatically

Comment: Can you please give an example about how to use the belongsTo association correctly in the controller so Cake only does 1 query ?